# How do I shear a selection in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, workflow, transform

I know I can scale by pulling on the handles with the *Select and transform* tool. Or similarly, rotate them by first clicking to toggle the handles.

[image: scaling an image]
[image: rotating an image]

But how do I [shear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping) an image?

Clicking again toggles the handles back to scaling mode.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Toggle to rotate mode, but drag the *edge* handles.

[image: shearing an image]